# Bitwise & operator in .NET framework method

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I found this method in a .NET framework class, it uses the Bitwise `&` 
operator to compare to byte arrays:

I think this functions is not optimal.
For example we have two strings:

1. live
2. life

The third character is different when comparing the two strings.
So when converting both into byte arrays, the third byte will be different and 
therefore the boolean variable flag will be false and will be false until the method finishes.

I would put behind this line:

```
flag = flag & a[i] == b[i];
if(flag==false)return false;
```

in order to prevent further loop execution.
So why is this implementation as it is right now?

```
public static bool AreByteArraysEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    if (a == null || b == null || (int)a.Length != (int)b.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)a.Length; i++)
    {
        flag = flag & a[i] == b[i];
    }
    return flag;
}
```

[image]

The class which holds the implementation resides in the **System.Web.WebPages.dll, Version=3.0.0.0**, **Namespace System.Web.Helpers**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace System.Web.Helpers
{
internal static class CryptoUtil
{
public static bool AreByteArraysEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    if (a == null || b == null || (int)a.Length != (int)b.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)a.Length; i++)
    {
        flag = flag & a[i] == b[i];
    }
    return flag;
}

public static byte[] ComputeSHA256(IList<string> parameters)
{
    byte[] numArray;
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            foreach (string parameter in parameters)
            {
                binaryWriter.Write(parameter);
            }
            binaryWriter.Flush();
            using (SHA256Cng sHA256Cng = new SHA256Cng())
            {
                byte[] numArray1 = sHA256Cng.ComputeHash(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, checked((int)memoryStream.Length));
                numArray = numArray1;
            }
        }
    }
    return numArray;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Where did you find that implementation?

Comment: You are right, your suggestion permits early termination of the loop and is an improvement. However, the `&` operator you mention is the _logical_ and, not the _bitwise_ and. Furthermore, the entire method can be replaced by the Linq extension method `SequenceEqual` which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: [There's a comment right above the method that explains exactly what the point is already.](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/CryptoUtil.cs) Why did you remove it from your question?

Comment: Great comment; the comment in the code completely explains why the loop is not terminated early.

Comment: It's a comparison method in the CryptoUtil class. Makes perfect sense...

Comment: @hvd while that is a good find and the OP should have included the comment in the question it still doesn't the "why".

Comment: Oh wait -- this looks like a decompiler's output. Well, now you know to look at the *actual* source code. :)

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Why does it make "perfect sense"?

Comment: @Nasreddine Yes, it does explain why. The OP's improvement would mean that timing attacks can be used to determine how many bytes match. That's what the comment is all about.

Comment: @hvd Thanks for the explanation. You should probably post it as an answer since OP's question is "So why is this implementation as it is right now?"

Comment: @Nasreddine It's to prevent a side channel attack where an attacker could measure timings to infer properties of the data.

Comment: @hvd there is no comment, when I inspect it with JustDecompile.

Comment: @hvd ah I see, ok, in the decompiled version there is no comment, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks like a decompiler's output. Don't look at a decompiler's output when [the actual source code](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/CryptoUtil.cs) is available. It may have relevant comments, and does here:

```
// This method is specially written to take the same amount of time
// regardless of where 'a' and 'b' differ. Please do not optimize it.
public static bool AreByteArraysEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b)
...
```

The improvement you've made would mean that the time needed to evaluate `AreByteArraysEqual` for two byte arrays of equal length depends on how many of the initial bytes match. Normally that's not a problem. For this method, it is, because it would allow the caller to obtain data (by continually trying until the first byte is right, then continually trying until the second byte is right, and so on) that's meant to remain secret.

Comment: +1. In addition to this answer here's [Wikipedia's article on the issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack)